# How to aggregate several rows into one?

Tags: sql

I want to get all countries where n amount of langauges are spoken into one tuple.

If I run this query:

```
            SELECT
               co.name
            FROM
                country co JOIN countrylanguage cl ON co.code = cl.countrycode
            GROUP BY
                co.name                                                        
            HAVING
                count(cl.language) = 6;
```

I get a result with each country in a separate row, but in the same column.

If I run the same, just with the aggregate command:

```
            SELECT
               array_agg(co.name)
            FROM
                country co JOIN countrylanguage cl ON co.code = cl.countrycode                                                    
            HAVING
                count(cl.language) = 6;
```

I get an empty result, 1 column, 0 rows.

With a "GROUP BY" included in the last query, I get all the countries in separate rows, but each country 6 times.

I want to get the results of the first query but as one tuple. How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: Derived table!

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `array_agg()`.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql it would be group_concat

```
SELECT
               group_concat(co.name)
            FROM
                country co JOIN countrylanguage cl ON co.code = cl.countrycode                                                    
            HAVING
                count(cl.language) = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of all countries that speak 6 languages, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT array_agg(cc.name)
FROM (SELECT co.name
      FROM country co JOIN
           countrylanguage cl
           ON co.code = cl.countrycode
      GROUP BY co.name                                                        
      HAVING count(cl.language) = 6
     ) cc;
```

If you want this in MySQL, then you would aggregate the results into a string using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT group_concat(cc.name)
FROM (SELECT co.name
      FROM country co JOIN
           countrylanguage cl
           ON co.code = cl.countrycode
      GROUP BY co.name                                                        
      HAVING count(cl.language) = 6
     ) cc;
```

Comment: This gave me the error that there's a missing FROM clause for co.name. Solution was to assign a name to it in the subquery with AS and then reference that name in the first SELECT.